# PHPWORD extract docx content

Tags: php, phpword

i'm using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to read and write file as doc docx or html.

But i have a problem to get all content of a docx file for example.

is there an example to get content of docx file or html file ? (i tried to use sample of phpword, but don't help me)

My wish is to extract all text from a file (docx, html or other) and save it in database as pure text.

Anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score -3):

We can use file_get_contents php function to get content of files

$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);

Hope this will help!

Comment: Yes thanks for ur help, but i try to use the PHPWORD functions, to read docx. It's not same thing as file_gets_content.
It's a different way to do this